# Compare values in 2 differents table with Contains

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL. I've got 2 tables in 2 differents base :

- Base1.dbo.TableA with more than 3 millions rows.
- Base2.dbo.TableB with 15 thousand rows

The goal is to extract all rows from table A where column "name" contains 80 % of de the column firstname +' '+ 80% of the column lastname from Table B.

For this i create a fulltext catalog for TableA and trigger on TableB (for each new entry).

Now i would like to analyse all in one time but i don't know how to organise my query

```
Select * from TableA x
where countains (name, (select substring(TableB.firstname, 0, (len(TableB.firstname)*80)/100)+ ' 
'+substring(TableB.lastname, 0, (len(TableB.lastname)*80)/100)))
```

It think it could be done maybe with a WHILE but TableB has not unique ID.

Edit 2021-02-18

A solution could be cursor usage

```
DECLARE @Count nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @Lname nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Fname nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @String nvarchar(100)


DECLARE Cur_test CURSOR FOR
    SELECT lastName, firstName FROM TableB

OPEN Cur_test

FETCH Cur_test INTO @Lname, @Fname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


SET @Lname = '"'+SUBSTRING(@Lname,0, (LEN(@Lname)*80)/100)+'*"'
SET @Fname='"'+SUBSTRING(@Fname,0, (LEN(@Fname)*80)/100)+'*"'
SET @String =@Lname+' AND '+@Fname
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE CONTAINS(name, @String))

IF @Count >=1
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE CONTAINS(name, @String)
    END

END

CLOSE Cur_test
DEALLOCATE Cur_test
```

I don't understand why it is so long. After 5 mn i haven't got any result.

Comment: I don't think `contains()` does what you think, if your intention is to use it on names.  It is looking at *word* matches, so "Andersen" is not going to match "Anderson".

Comment: It's working like this for any new records. This is what i've done on the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH resultTable AS (
SELECT 

substring(TableB.firstname, 0, (len(TableB.firstname)*80)/100) as FName,
substring(TableB.lastname, 0, (len(TableB.lastname)*80)/100) as LName

FROM TableB)
select TableA.* from resultTable,TableA
WHERE TableA.name LIKE  '%' + resultTable.FName + ' ' + resultTable.LName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
DECLARE @Count nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @Lname nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Fname nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @String nvarchar(100)


DECLARE Cur_test CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT lastName, firstName FROM TableB

OPEN Cur_test

FETCH Cur_test INTO @Lname, @Fname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


SET @Lname = '"'+SUBSTRING(@Lname,0, (LEN(@Lname)*80)/100)+'*"'
SET @Fname='"'+SUBSTRING(@Fname,0, (LEN(@Fname)*80)/100)+'*"'
SET @String =@Lname+' AND '+@Fname
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE CONTAINS(name, @String))

IF @Count >=1
    BEGIN
        --Do your action
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableA] WHERE CONTAINS(name, @String)
    END
   FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_test INTO @Lname, @Fname
END

CLOSE Cur_test
DEALLOCATE Cur_test
```